# Find the list item of Pairs with the minimum value

Tags: kotlin

```kotlin
val index = listOf("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno")
    .mapIndexed { index, v ->
        var t = 0
        var p = 0
        for (s in v) {
            t += ("deh".get(p++).toInt() - s.toInt()).absoluteValue
        }
        Pair(index, v)
    }
    .minOf {
        val iterator = iterator<Pair<Int, String>>(it)
        if (!iterator.hasNext()) throw NoSuchElementException()
        var minValue = iterator.next().second
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            val v = selector(iterator.next())
            minValue = minOf(minValue, v)
        }
        return minValue
    }
```

This is an alternative solution and works, but I am wondering if the solution can be done using mapOf as shown above?

```kotlin
val index = listOf("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "jad", "jaa", "mno")
    .mapIndexed { index, v ->
        var t = 0
        var p = 0
        for (s in v) {
            t += ("jac".get(p++).toInt() - s.toInt()).absoluteValue
        }
        Pair(index, t)
    }.toSortedSet(compareBy { it.second })
    .first()
```

I create a map of Pairs and I want to find the index of the map item where the Pair with the value (the second item in the pair) is the lowest value (minimum) of all the pairs. If possible, I would like to use the minOf function. The first example above will not compile because of bugs in the minOf function. Not sure how to iterate over the map of Pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`minBy {}`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/min-by.html) to get the minimum value from a collection, although often it's safer to use [`minByOrNull {}`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/min-by-or-null.html) in case no minimal value can be computed (which could happen if the list is empty).

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.absoluteValue

fun main() {
  val minElement = listOf("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "jad", "jaa", "mno")
    .minByOrNull { v ->
      var t = 0
      var p = 0
      for (s in v) {
        t += ("jac".get(p++).toInt() - s.toInt()).absoluteValue
      }
      t
    }
  println(minElement)
}
```

```
jad
```

[*Run in Kotlin Playground*](https://pl.kotl.in/uwAT38PcJ)

If you also want to find the index of the minimal value, then you can use [`withIndex()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-index.html), which will pair each list element with its index.

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.absoluteValue

fun main() {
  val minIndexedElement = listOf("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "jad", "jaa", "mno")
    .withIndex() // adds the index to each element 
    .minByOrNull { (_, v) ->
      var t = 0
      var p = 0
      for (s in v) {
        t += ("jac".get(p++).toInt() - s.toInt()).absoluteValue
      }
      t
    }
  println(minIndexedElement)
}
```

```
IndexedValue(index=4, value=jad)
```

[*Run in Kotlin Playground*](https://pl.kotl.in/M5DiVxIIJ)

Comment: Your solution returns the string. I want to return the index. Your solution won't work. Guess I didn't make that clear enough, so I updated my question.

Comment: Your second solution is what I was looking for. Oddly though, if you put a breakpoint inside of the minByOrNull, it only gets hit once. You can't break on each value. Any idea what that is?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to extract the character codes from "jar" and from each item, and then to [zip](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-transformations.html#zip) the two code lists. *zip* allows for a *transform* closure in which the calculation with the two codes can be made. After that *sum()* gives the wanted value.

```
data class Result(val index: Int, val string: String, val computedValue: Int)

val list = listOf("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "jad", "jaa", "mno")

val result = list
    .mapIndexed { idx, str ->
      val codes1 = "jac".toCharArray().map { it.code }
      val codes2 = str.toCharArray().map { it.code }
      val computed = codes1.zip(codes2) { code1, code2 -> (code1 - code2).absoluteValue }.sum()
      Result(idx, str, computed)
    }
    .minByOrNull { it.computedValue }

println(result)   // Output: Result(index=4, string=jad, computedValue=1)
```

Instead of the helper data class *Result* a *Triple* instance could be used:

```
  ...
  Triple(idx, str, computed)
}
.minByOrNull { it.third }

// Output: (4, jad, 1)
```

Or if the calculated value is not needed, it could be dropped like that:

```
...
?.let { it.first to it.second }

// Output: (4, jad)
```